# A map from S to T

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $S=(0,1)\cup(1, 2)\cup(3, 4)$

$T=\{0,1, 2, 3\}$.

Then which of the following statements is(are) true?

(A) There are infinitely many functions from S to T

(B) There are infinitely many strictly increasing functions from S to T

(C) The number of continuous functions from S to T is at most 120

(D) Every continuous function from S to T is differentiable

First of all,
We define a function f .s.t.

$f:S\rightarrow T$,

S is the domain with a collection of unioned open interval sets. Firstly am I correct in saying that. Eg the open interval set (0,1) is a infinite collection of real numbers between 0 and 1 exclusive and so on for (1,2) and (2,3). Then the Codomain T is a finite set with 4 elements. We see that S is a partitioned set that is built from a union of disjoint infinite sets. I realize that I made the assumption that the sets are a infinite collection of real numbers between the two exclusive elements like (0,1) in the first partition of S. The domain is a infinite collection of elements and the codomain is a finite collection of elements and if we were to produce a mapping between the two, there would be a infinite number of functions capable of doing this? (Not sure how to concretely show this) and for possibly showing or disproving that they are all strictly increasing? , would this mean that for a given x and y and for $x+\epsilon$ and $y+\delta$ , $y+\delta > y$ for a input $x+\epsilon, \forall \epsilon > 0$. Again these observations are just to help me understand the problem but don’t necessarily help in solving it, also my presentation is rather loose and not very concrete. Also another interesting question , if I were to graph some potential $f:S\rightarrow T$ what would it look it?
Thanks!